# Unity 2d infinite map generation with walls

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, procedural-generation

I trying to make 2d game in unity. I want to make something similar to guy in this video: https://youtu.be/OXRUEqbV2oM

I want to make world generation similar to his, but I was looking on some YouTube tutorials and didn't find how to do it.

If somebody can help me I would appreciate it.

I was looking all over the YouTube and internet and didn't find any way to do it. Even tutorial about procedural generation didn't help me.

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You should make **tiles**(parts of your world), and **randomly** generate them.

Currently i'm trying to make it,
it's problably going to take a while.

Comment: Yeah, but it will result in making dead ends or  closing me in really small area. If you make it and it works can you please share it with me. Good luck!

Comment: I unfortunately don't know how to solve the problem with dead ends. i once used the code to make an rpg, and in the tiles that i've made, i didn't put any walls. sorry if i can't help :(

Answer (score 0):

**This is what i made.**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class WorldBuilder : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject[] Tiles;
    private float RandomNumber;
    private float PositionToSpawnX;
    public float PositionToSpawnY;

    private void Start()
    {
        RandomNumber = Random.Range(0, 3);
        PositionToSpawnX = 0;
        Destroy(gameObject, 5);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if(RandomNumber == 0)
        {
            Instantiate(Tiles[0], new Vector3(PositionToSpawnX, PositionToSpawnY, 0), Quaternion.identity);
            RandomNumber = Random.Range(0, 3);
            PositionToSpawnX += 5;
        }

        if (RandomNumber == 1)
        {
            Instantiate(Tiles[1], new Vector3(PositionToSpawnX, PositionToSpawnY, 0), Quaternion.identity);
            RandomNumber = Random.Range(0, 3);
            PositionToSpawnX += 5;
        }

        if (RandomNumber == 2)
        {
            Instantiate(Tiles[2], new Vector3(PositionToSpawnX, PositionToSpawnY, 0), Quaternion.identity);
            RandomNumber = Random.Range(0, 3);
            PositionToSpawnX += 5;
        }

        if (RandomNumber == 3)
        {
            Instantiate(Tiles[3], new Vector3(PositionToSpawnX, PositionToSpawnY, 0), Quaternion.identity);
            RandomNumber = Random.Range(0, 3);
            PositionToSpawnX += 5;
        }
    }
}
```

You Get the tiles you've Made and put the in the **Tiles** Array, and run the game(my tiles are 5 unit in scale, if you want it to work you should make your tiles the same size as mine).

if you didn't understand something you can tell me (:

Comment: Thanks, I will try it when I get home. But I wanna make a world with rooms (you cant go through walls, won't it make dead ends or block me in very smal area?). So how do I have to create tiles 5 units in scale? Is it like 5 pixels per tile?